# Programmatically creating User with devise and first_or_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, activemodel

I've got to programmatically create users via an api -- I'm able to create users passing in the proper params ie:

```
x={"email"=>"kid@kid.com", "username"=>"levi", "password"=>"password","password_confirmation" => "password", "firstname"=>"Bob", "lastname"=>"Smith"}
u=User.new(x)
u.valid?
```

And able to check if this is a valid user before saving, etc. But the problem is that if params such as username or email already already exist for another user I'll get an error on save.

Now I can check if a user exists already (ie `u=User.where(username: x['username'])` or `u=User.where(email: x['email']`) -- and that might be enough but I'm wondering if there's a way of doing `u=User.where(x).first_or_create with devise`?  Works generally with other models but not devise.

Comment: What doesn't work about using `find_or_create` with Devise?

Comment: If you have have uniqueness validations for email and username `.valid?` will actually check the database to see if the value exists. Perhaps if you add a bit more details about what you are trying to achieve we can point you in the right direction. Are you trying to do this from a controller or a seed file?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with find_or_create_by (http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by) is that it will try to find a user matching *all* of the attributes you pass in as criteria. It is rarely a useful method. Instead, wrap it in your model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.username_find_or_create(attributes = {})
    User.create(attributes) unless User.exists?(attributes.slice(:username, :email))
  end
end
```

([Exists](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/exists%3F/class) is faster than where)